# How to efficiently fill a column of dataframe with values calculated from other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stockquotes

I am trying to fill a dataframe (*elist*) with cumulative returns of firms and cumulative market returns. This can be done by looping through the elist dataframe using `iterrows`, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593859/why-cant-iterrows-do-math-and-instead-returns-integer-values-where-these-shou). However, this is slow.

I am looking for a more potent, faster solution.

The raw returns that are the inputs for the cumulative return calculations originate from two dataframes (ri, rm). The results should then be recorded in columns of *elist*. See example below, using the data in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r69b54q2zw1wp7q/cumrets.zip?dl=0).

Before running the `iterrows` loop, *elist* looks like:

```
    permno  begdat      enddat   return vwretd
0   11628   2012-03-31  2013-03-31  NaN NaN
1   11628   2012-06-30  2013-06-30  NaN NaN
2   11628   2012-09-30  2013-09-30  NaN NaN
3   11628   2012-12-31  2013-12-31  NaN NaN
4   11628   2013-03-31  2014-03-31  NaN NaN
```

After running the loop *elist* should look like:

```
    permno   begdat     enddat      return      vwretd
0   11628   2012-03-31  2013-03-31  0.212355    0.133429
1   11628   2012-06-30  2013-06-30  0.274788    0.198380
2   11628   2012-09-30  2013-09-30  0.243590    0.198079
3   11628   2012-12-31  2013-12-31  0.299277    0.304479
4   11628   2013-03-31  2014-03-31  0.303147    0.208454
```

Here is the code that relies on iterrows, which is slow:

```
import os,sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rm     = pd.read_csv('rm_so.csv') # market return
ri     = pd.read_csv('ri_so.csv') # firm return
elist  = pd.read_csv('elist_so.csv') # table to be filled with cumlative returns over a period (begdat to enddat)
for index, row in elist.iterrows():
    #fill cumulative market return
    elist.loc[index, 'vwretd']=rm.loc[(rm['date']>row['begdat']) & (rm['date']<=row['enddat']),'vwretd'].product()-1    
    #fill cumulative firm return
    r = ri.loc[(ri['permno']==row['permno']),]
    elist.loc[index, 'return'] = r.loc[(r['date']>row['begdat']) & (r['date']<=row['enddat']),'ret'].product()-1
```

It would be great to see this process running faster!